# typeRoots tsconfig.json set for node_modules/@types but vs code still not recognizing despite installing all of the associated @types

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have installed various `@types` which are inside my `node_modules`

E.g:

`node_modules/@types/express`
`node_modules/@types/mongoose`

etc...

I have even tried to set inside the `tsconfig.json` the `compilerOptions.typeRoots` setting for `["node_modules/@types"]`.

Despite all of this when i load up my .ts files, the VS Code Problems tab says ...

```
Cannot find module 'express' or its corresponding type declarations.
Cannot find module 'mongoose' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

All I'm trying to do is get automatic type support and have intellisense work. I don't want to have to run around each file and add type references.

How do I setup TypeScript properly. I know this question has been asked 1000 times probably. I just cant seem to get it working. Any assistance greatly appreciated. I'm eager to actually start coding and spending less time getting the IDE to function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that after disabling/uninstalling the Deno (VS Code extension) from denoland, my TS Code has now reverted back to using the built-in VS Code language server.